# jQuery .animate() - increment number in .each()

Tags: jquery, load, jquery-animate, each

If there have 3 images. The animation will run 3 times at the same time. Cuz i want to do someting at 30 and 100 values ONE TIME. Is there any solution of this.

```
img.each(function(e){
    var image = $(this);
    image.load(function(){ // load 3 images
        currentValue += eachOfImg; // eachOfImg = 100/3
        jQuery({someValue: startValue}).animate({someValue: currentValue}, {
            duration: 3000,
            step: function() {
                console.log('currentValue:',this.someValue);
                if(someValue == 30) // do something
                if(someValue == 100) // do something
                $('.text').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue) + "%");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The Chrome console output is:

```
(3) currentValue: 0
(8) currentValue: 1 
    currentValue: 2 
(2) currentValue: 1 
    currentValue: 2 
    currentValue: 1 
(2) currentValue: 2 
    currentValue: 1 
(2) currentValue: 2 
    currentValue: 1 
    currentValue: 2 
    currentValue: 3 
    currentValue: 1 
    currentValue: 2
```

i expect it will:

```
    currentValue: 0
    currentValue: 1 
    currentValue: 2 
    currentValue: 3 
    currentValue: 4 
    currentValue: 5 
    currentValue: 6 
    currentValue: 7 
    currentValue: 8 
    currentValue: 9 
    ...
```

Thanks

Comment: That code does'nt really make much sense, and I think you need to explain better what you are trying to do. The value for where the animation is in the process is a parameter in the step function, usually named `now`, like : `step: function(now, fx) { if (now>30) }`

Comment: Either make the selector specific to a single image, or include a flag in your `if` condition, something like `if (value == 30 && !functionExecutedYet) {}`